# PowerShell ErrorRecord

Tags: powershell, exception

when I run a script and it throws an exception, another script is run (log script).
I have to give the current error object to the log script.

```
try
{
    New-Item -Path 'E:\test.txt' -ItemType 'File' -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    Write-Log -ErrorObject $Error 
}
```

How can I access the error object of the first script directly from the second script?
The best way would be to use the .Net framework (System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord).
I want to output a complete error message.

Comment: How do you invoke the 2nd script on error?

Comment: See code example.

Comment: `$Error` type is ArrayList; use `Write-Log -ErrorObject $_` inside the `catch` block…